# Creating a database within Apple Automator

Tags: mysql, automator

I can create a database from terminal using:

```
mysql -u "root" -p"root" -e "create database mydatabase;"
```

However, that doesn't work inside automator - no error, just doesn't work.

I am am using the 'Run shell Script' in bash mode.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that although I had setup a bash profile in the terminal, I hadn't within 'Automator' which runs it's own version of bash (I thought it used the systems).
So it couldn't find the mySql command.